# Download all the heteroComplex protein PDB IDs in RCSB Protein Data Bank

Tags: python, r, bioinformatics, biopython

I want to Download all the HeteroComplex protein PDB IDs, which are in the Protein Data Bank (all the PDB IDs which composed of two or more different types of chain. For example PDB ID XXXX which will be made up of chain A and Chain B. Not with two chain 'A's.) . Does anybody know a python programme to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should have a read here first: [ask]

Comment: Hope now its fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want a PDB structure with different entities (https://www.rcsb.org/pages/help/advancedsearch/numberOfEntities):

> Unlike chains, entities do not include duplicate copies.

You can search for PDB structures containing two or more different protein entities and download them using the Python package *Biotite* (https://www.biotite-python.org):

```py
import biotite.database.rcsb as rcsb
pdb_ids = rcsb.search(rcsb.EntityCountQuery(min=2, entity_type="protein"))
rcsb.fetch(pdb_ids, format="pdb", target_path="some/directory", verbose=True)
```

Comment: Spot on. Thank you very much